# It's posible write a dynamic rowkey filter in apache beam for bigtable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, apache-beam-io

I am looking for a way to filter based on current time in a dataflow job.

I have the following code to read from bigtable but I can't find the way to generate a dynamic scanner or a callable function or lamda to be able to pass the date as a search parameter.

```
RowFilter filter = RowFilter.newBuilder().setRowKeyRegexFilter(ByteString.copyFromUtf8("2020-06-05#.*#")).build(); 
PCollection<ObjectDto> collection = pipeline.apply("Read",
        BigtableIO.read()
                .withBigtableOptions(optionsBuilder)
                .withTableId("table")
                .withRowFilter(filter));
```

I need something like that

```
PCollection<ObjectDto> collection = pipeline.apply("Read",
        BigtableIO.read()
                .withBigtableOptions(optionsBuilder)
                .withTableId("table")
                .withRowFilter(RowFilter.newBuilder().setRowKeyRegexFilter(
                    new SerializableFunction(){
                        Date d = new Date();
                        return DateFormat.getDate(d) + "#.*#"+DateFormat.getTime(d);
                    }  
                ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that currently the [BigTableIO.Read](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.Read.html) class only supports a [ValueProvider](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/ValueProvider.html) to specify either the ProjectId, InstanceId or the TableId. This allows creating a template and changing these parameters dynamically; however, it's currently not possible to pass a [RowFilter](https://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/bigtable/v2/RowFilter.html) object in this way.

However, if you are running your pipeline without a template, you can create the Date RowFilter for your use case like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date) + "#.*#";
RowFilter filter = RowFilter.newBuilder().setRowKeyRegexFilter(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(currentDate)).build();
```

And later, pass it to your pipeline:

```
pipeline.apply("Read",
   BigtableIO.read()
      .withProjectId("<PROJECT_ID>")
       .withInstanceId("<INSTANCE_ID>")
       .withTableId(“TABLE_ID”)
       .withRowFilter(filter));
```

In this way, every time you run your pipeline, the filter will be created with the current date.